# Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown

Tags: 2010, error, authentication, claims-based-auth, cookie

I'm on 2010 Sharepoint. some users get the error when they're logged in with "remember me" checked and being inactive for more than 2 days. we have the cookies set to expires after 2 days and it suppose to kick you out and make you logon again. PLEASE HELP! here's the full error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. 
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Parameter name: encodedValue 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Exception of type
>   'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Parameter name: encodedValue
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:  [ArgumentException: Exception of type
>   'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Parameter name: encodedValue]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String
>   encodedValue) +25971126
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKey(String
>   encodedIdentityClaimSuffix) +296
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHeaderManager.AddIsapiHeaders(HttpContext
>   context, String encodedUrl, NameValueCollection headers) +845
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea) +352
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but couldn't.  I set up a forms auth app (backed by my local AD using `LdapMembershipProvider` and `LdapRoleProvider`) and set my tokens to expire after 2 minutes. No matter how I fiddled with it I always got redirected to the sign in page.  Can you provide more information about your setup that might be affecting the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I just Opened the IIS server -->central Administration --> Authentication

in the authentication I just disabled the Forms Authentication.

After that I can able to view the CentralAdminstration.

http://everestheightsforu.blogspot.com.eg/2014/02/resolving-error-while-opening.html